# Como hacer que el color del menú <nav></nav> cambie en base al color de fondo que tienes aplicado en ese momento

Tags: html, css, scss

Alguien sabe como puedo cambiar el estilo a un elemento al llegar a una posicion o etiqueta del body ?
Lo quiero hacer con un navbar de color negro que cuando llegue a una posicion cambie a color blanco.
Que sea responsive tambien.

index.html

```
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#inicio">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sobremi">Sobre mi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#habilidades">Habilidades</a></li>
                <li><a href="#proyectos">Proyectos</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <div id="inicio"></div>
            <div id="sobremi"></div>
            <div id="habilidades"></div>
            <div id="proyectos"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que al hacer scroll, el background del div cambie de color?

Comment: Con javascript puedes manipular los elementos del DOM y modificar las propiedades de los elementos html con css

Comment: Pista rápida: Podría servirte [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Comment: Muchas gracias padaleiana, le eché un ojo y creo que me puede servir

Comment: @padaleiana ya lo logre hacer → https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/517013/237951

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si he entendido bien lo que quieres hacer, pero creo que quieres hacer que el color de tu menú `<nav></nav>` cambie en base al color de fondo que tienes aplicado en ese momento. No se si esto se puede hacer, pero te dejo con una posible solución:

```
<script>
    //Activamos un addEventListener de Scroll en el contenedor "main"
    let main = document.querySelector(".main");
    main.addEventListener("scroll",()=>{
        //En scrollTop estoy obteniendo la posición de la página en al cual me situo
        //console.log(main.scrollTop); para verlo más claro
        scrollDiff(main.scrollTop);
    })
 
 function scrollDiff(scrollPos){
     //Anchors de tu navBar
    let navbar = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar ul li a");
    //Borde de el listado
    let navbarBorder = document.querySelector(".navbar ul");
    //Recorremos el nodeList de todos los elementos del menú
    navbar.forEach(attribute=>{
        if(scrollPos <= 855){
            //Aquí tienes el fondo verde
            attribute.style.color = "black";
            navbarBorder.style.borderColor = "black";
        }else if(scrollPos > 856 && scrollPos <=1787){
            //Aquí tienes el fondo blanco
            attribute.style.color = "green";
            navbarBorder.style.borderColor = "green";
        }else if(scrollPos > 1789 && scrollPos <= 2725){
             //Aquí tienes el fondo azul
             attribute.style.color = "aquamarine";
             navbarBorder.style.borderColor = "aquamarine";
        }else if(scrollPos >2726 && scrollPos <= 2799){
            //Aquí tienes el fondo negro
             attribute.style.color = "white";
             navbarBorder.style.borderColor = "white";
        }else{
            //Vuelve a un color por defecto
            attribute.style.color = "black";
            navbarBorder.style.borderColor = "black";
        }
    });
  
 }
</script>
```

Mediante JavaScript puedes determinar la posición en la que te encuentras de la página por el scroll, puedes hacer que si te encuentras en ciertas posiciones le apliques un color o otro al menú, aunque esta manera no es demasiado buena, si quieres hacer la página responsive este método no es el más adecuado.

Comment: Si lo mismo quería hacer pero no me sirve porque quiero que sea responsive. Pero Gracias igual por tomarte el tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre obteniendo la distancia del top del elemento donde quiero que cambie y cuando el scroll llegue a esa distancia cambie de color:

```
document.addEventListener(
    "scroll",
    (e) => {
        if (
            document.querySelector(".main").scrollTop >=
            document.querySelector("#proyectos").offsetTop
        ) {
            document.querySelector("nav > ul").style.border = "#fff solid 2px";
            document.querySelectorAll("nav a").forEach((e) => {
                e.classList.add("navdark");
            });
        } else {
            document.querySelector("nav > ul").style.border = "#111 solid 2px";
            document.querySelectorAll("nav a").forEach((e) => {
                e.classList.remove("navdark");
            });
        }
    },
    true
);
```